# Load the dump file to another repo directory

Tags: svn

All,

Can anyone help to resolve the problem for migrating my old server svn repo to new server svn repo.

Here are my issues ,
   I got dump file from my old server

1. I have created repo in the new server
2. and also created svn directory in the same repo
3. Now i want to move my dump repo into the directory of the new repo

   i tried this below command svnadmin load --parent-dir /path/reponame/directory repo < dump file.

   But it was giving me an error "reponame/format  file not found" .

   Please anyone give me an good solution for this issue.

Thanks n advance

Comment: I don't know (because I have no idea what `--parent-dir  /path/reponame/directory` means for `svnadmin load`) but you could at least understand what is happenning by `strace`-ing the `svnadmin` command.

Answer (score 0):

P. 2 is not needed and bad - you must load dump in the root of previously created repo in simplest case

- svnadmin create /path/to/repo
- svnadmin load /path/to/repo < dumpfile